# New log file without server restart

Tags: logging, websphere-6.1, logfiles

In this link, they explain how to generate a new log file without restarting sql server: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/09/sql-server-recycle-error-log-create-new-log-file-without-server-restart/

Is there a way to generate a new SystemOut.log file without restarting the WebSphere application server?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the "maximum size" and "maximum number of historical log files".  See the [Java virtual machine (JVM) log settings](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/utrb_jvmlogs.html) article in the InfoCenter.

Additionally, you can force an immediate rollover of the logs using the `rolloverLogFileImmediate` operation of the [TraceService](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.wsfep.doc/web/mbeanDocs/TraceService.html) MBean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I usually do in a Development environments in Unix.

Whenever I need fresh files, I simply do a echo > SystemOut.log and this simply works well for most development purposes.

Obviously, you can't do this in other environments.